# How to use ASP.NET Tag Helpers inside html table cells

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

In this [Microsoft Tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html#create-views) how can we display the html cell labels and values using [ASP.NET HTML Tag Helpers](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro.html)? For instance, in the following code from the tutorial instead of using `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BlogId)<\td>` I would like to use tag helper. I tried using `<td><label asp-for="item.BlogId"></label><\td>` but intellisense does not recognize `item in item.BlogId` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag Helpers in label will display the Display attribute name property. For displaying the value BlogId in view, you can do something like this.

```
<table>
@foreach (SampleApp.Controllers.Blog item in Model)
{
    <tr><td>@item.BlogId</td></tr>
}
</table>
```

If you require, you can wrap the value in label. No need to use asp-for attribute.

Comment: I apologize for marking your response as `Answer` this late.

Comment: Can you explain why asp-for="item.BlogId" does not work @nam